# Are there any companies that do season ticket loans for the London Underground?

Tags: tickets, london

I've seen a few companies that have offered season ticket loan reimbursement (pay back in equal instalments per month) for using the London Underground but I can't seem to find them now. Are there any companies that still do this?

Comment: Normally it's your own company that offers it - it has [special beneficial tax treatment](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/green-transport/travel-plans.htm)

Comment: Questions about things involving being in one place for multiple months aren't really on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

This is an usual benefit for employees in companies based in London, but this is only available if you are a resident and work for one of these companies. I doubt there is such a service for visitors.